# how to send data from a python file to html file that are in a separate projects via a url (not having html as a template)

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

how to send data from a python file to html file that has a js code that are in a separate projects via a url (not having html as a template) and vice versa?

i think i need to use AJAX function and json object but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to encode your data as JSON (or something else, but JSON is the easiest) within your Python function, then make that Python function visible visible to the web via something like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), and, as you correctly surmised, pull the data with AJAX in javascript on the web app's side.

In the end, it'll look something like this.

```
import json

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/get-data/")
def get_data():
    data = my_function()
    data = json.dumps(data)
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Where `my_function()` is the current function you've written that returns the data needed.  Your web app can then get the data at `http://your-machines-web-address.com/get-data/`.

Comment: I am using python django so what is flask I don't know it

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't understand your question.  If you're already using django there should be no problem making some data you have in that app available on the internet.