# flask session variable not being registered as html tag

Tags: python, html, json, flask

I have tried
[Passing HTML to template using Flask/Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206344/passing-html-to-template-using-flask-jinja2) , 
[converting json to string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600003/converting-json-to-string-in-python) , 
[How to access session variables in jinja 2 - Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42013067/how-to-access-session-variables-in-jinja-2-flask) , 
[how to send data from a python file to html file that are in a separate projects via a url (not having html as a template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165993/how-to-send-data-from-a-python-file-to-html-file-that-are-in-a-separate-projects)

I am trying to pass a variable that was stored in flask sessions to html but the html tags are showing up like they are escaped. I have tried to us-escape them, decode them from unicode, decode them to from JSON, use flask markup with passing them as {{ variable|safe }}, parsing them (although I didn't think this was the problem anyway), and passing the varible in directly {{session['final']}}. All to no avail. And here is my code

```
...
final = '<p>' + Plast + ', ' + Pfirst + ' ' + Pmiddle + '. ' + '“' + PartTitle + '.' + '” ' + '<i>' + PwebTitle + '</i>' + ', ' + Ppublish + ', ' + Pday + ' ' + Pmonth + '. ' + Pyear + ', ' + Purl + '.' + '</p>'

session['final'] = final
return redirect(url_for('final'))
```

```
@app.route('/final', methods=['GET'])
def final():
    inpre = session['final']
    outpost = Markup(inpre)
    return render_template("final.html", finalCite=outpost)
```

Html

```
<div id="text">{{ finalCite|safe }}</div>
```

The problem is that the variable is returned to the web page as `<p>...<i>content</i>...</p>` and not as *...content...*

Comment: Try removing the mark up. Just pass the string as is. Also try removing safe

Comment: Yes I have tried that and it doesn't work, also thank you for answering!

Comment: Can you print the session variable